# Arch Linux won't connect to WiFi through wpa_supplicant

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

First of all, I am an ultra noob when it comes to Linux.
I recently installed arch in my laptop through the built-in installer.
I installed GNOME as well and I have installed wpa_supplicant to connect to WiFi (aside from the NetworkManager).

Now when I type wpa_passphrase "myssid" password it loads everything like this:

```
   network={
      ssid="myssid"
      #psk="password"
      psk=(a very large string)
}
```

Then, when I type:
`sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wl3s0`

It shows me this sequence of text:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211:Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211:deint ifname=wl3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Could not read interface wl3s0 flags: No such device
wl3s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
wl3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
```

I have tried modifying the .conf file of wpa_supplicant as well as just copying the exemplary .conf file in /usr/share/doc/ with no results.

I have tried working with network manager and iwctl but N.M. doesn't work and I haven't installed iw in my machine.

Comment: My random guess: interface name typo: more probably wlp3s0 (notice the p). To be sure, you should check the output of `ip -br link`.

Comment: thanks for the guess but i hadn't realize i had iw in my laptop after all